# Tailwind CSS not applying styles

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am currently building a react-express web app and today I ran into many bugs, The first issue was with `Webpack-5`. I solved it by downgrading the version to `4.0.3` but when I started the react-app, the CSS was not working so I thought it might be an error with `Node JS` version so I installed the latest version but that caused another bug so I installed the `LTS 16.15.1` version but the CSS still did not work. So the next thing I did was reinstall `tailwind` but that still did not fix it. I don't receive any error messages in the console or in the terminal.

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
export const plugins = {
  tailwindcss: {},
  autoprefixer: {},
};
```

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "sass": "^1.52.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3"
  }
```

Here is the link to the [project](https://github.com/Rohith-JN/npm_search) if that helps in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue by following this: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/02/tailwindcss-react-project/.
But am still not sure why it stopped working suddenly. The only problem with this solution is that on `npm start` it builds the CSS and outputs it to another file. The problem with that is that I have to restart the server everytime I make a change to the CSS.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, the solution for me was in the content array in the tailwind.config.json where I specified the path to the folder where I what the styles to get applied[image]

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",  
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./page-section/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: "#366B45"
      },

      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["Inter", "sans-serif"],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: shouldn't just have
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,tsx,jsx}",
  ],

be sufficient though? As it involves the entire project.
I'm still having issues setting this up and can't quite get an answer anywhere

Comment: @RafaelSantos nextjs projects dont have a src folder in the root by default

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following in the `index.css` file

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: I had already done that, but it did not work

Comment: Try to restart the server

Comment: That’s the first thing I did but did not work